# abstract class&interface

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

can u tell what is the main difference between abstract class and interface in java.?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126938/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract-class

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558164/how-do-you-decide-between-using-an-abstract-class-and-an-interface

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is Abstract class is CLASS and interface is Interface.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class has one or more methods that are not implemented (i.e. only the method's prototype is declared). It may have one or more methods that are implemented.

In an interface none of the methods are implemented. It only has prototypes for methods and can't have any methods that are implemented unlike an abstract class. Also, more than one interface can be inherited by another class, but multiple inheritance is not allowed when inheriting from abstract classes.